# How to deserialize a java map

Tags: java, dictionary, go, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to de-serialize bytes into an object in Go, which was serialized into bytes in Java, in the following way:

```
//myMap is an instance of Java TreeMap<String, Object>

ByteArrayOutputStream a = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream b = new GZIPOutputStream(a);
ObjectOutputStream c = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
c.writeObject(myMap);
c.close();
byte[] bytes = a.toByteArray()
```

Below are the attempts I made

step1 - uncompressed the bytes (in the variable *result*) using

```
   //att is the byte array received 

   buf := bytes.NewBuffer(att)
   reader, _ := gzip.NewReader(buf)
   defer reader.Close()
   result , _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
```

step2 - read object out of uncompressed bytes - *but failed*

```
    var decodedMap map[string]interface{}
    d := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(*result*))
    err = d.Decode(&decodedMap)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
 
    error = gob: encoded unsigned integer out of range
```

But when I convert the (byte array) *result* to string in Go, I see the encoded treemap details and the contents

```
   map:  �� sr java.util.TreeMap��>-%j� Lt NAMEt JOHNt AGEt 32t LOCODEsr java.lang.Long;���̏#� J valuexr java.lang.Number������  xp  y
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You can rewrite Java's [ObjectInputStream](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java) in Go (the relevant parts) to read a Java serialized stream. Not easy as 1-2-3 but definitely not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (easily) deserialize those maps in Go, because the serialized data contains Java-specific data, data required to instantiate and initialize the original Java class (`java.util.TreeMap` in this case), which is obviously unknown to a Go app. Java object serialization and the encoding implemented by [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) have nothing to do with each other; the former is specific to Java and the latter is specific to Go.

Instead try to serialize the Java object in a language-neutral way, e.g. to JSON, which you can decode in Go (or in any other language).